# Laravel php artisan serve on remote server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, serve

I tried to start serve laravel on a remote by the followed command:

```
php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8888
```

I am able to telnet `remote-server-ip 8888`.

But when I accessed through `remote-server-ip:8888`, what I got is:

> Error 404
>
> Houston, We Have A Problem. Not Found

I think it's a Apache2 Error page. Any chance to solve it?

Comment: `php artisan serve` not using apache anyway. It's executing php built-in server and very not recommended to run it in production environment. It's just for development environment. You should configure your `apache` or `nginx` correctly to run your laravel app. 

http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Comment: I known, but i only try to get to understand why i can not connect to served server